# Brand New Macbook Pro (Mid 2012) already with 2 cycle counts

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

Yesterday I unboxed a MacBook Pro (Mid 2012) and I am disappointed that the battery has less than its "manufacturer capacity" and has 2 cycles already. Is that normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I bought my MacBook Pro, it also had 2 cycles used. I think it's normal and it's probably a part of the in-factory testing.

As for the manufacture capacity - it's perfectly normal for it to deteriorate, but it's going to do it gradually (and slowly if you take care of your battery)

How much capacity has it actually lost?

Comment: Thanks for the response. My sister got a MD101 and when she got it it was 0 cycle counts.

Comment: I'm glad somebody else also has this issue, then I suppose it is normal. I lost around 2% of the manufacture capacity

Answer (score 0):

I unboxed my new MacBook Pro (Mid 2012) yesterday and it have 0 cycle

So i don't think it's ok !

(did you get the wizard(1st time configuration) when you open it !? )